# fluid image resize with browser resize

Tags: jquery, resize, resize-image

Does anyone know how to make the image resize to the browser using jquery like this

http://www.ellenrogers.co.uk/photoshoot/folly

?

Comment: Did you check it out in FireBug? Look at line 15 of standard.js (`$(window).resize()`)

Comment: doesn't work in ie9 - anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

That site uses this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $img = $("#theImage");
    var ratio;
    var offsetX = $img.offset().left;
    var offsetY = $img.offset().top;

    $(window).load(function () {
        ratio = $img.width() / $img.height();
        $(this).resize();
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        var availWidth = viewportWidth - offsetX - 25;
        var availHeight = viewportHeight - offsetY - 25;

        if (availWidth / availHeight > ratio) {
            $img.height(availHeight);
            $img.width(availHeight * ratio);
        } else {
            $img.width(availWidth);
            $img.height(availWidth / ratio);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: in my website its throwing an error TypeError: $img.offset(...) is undefined
 

var offsetY = $img.offset().top;   can you tell me why ?

Comment: @VikramAnandBhushan: I can only guess. Do you have an image with an ID of `theImage`? Is jQuery definitely loaded?

Comment: oh I fixed it bro it was happening because #theImage this id was not loaded before as I was using Image Carousal . So I added this code after the carousal  and it works